# HTTP Status 500 - javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25, response: 421

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

Here is my send email code.
I am getting error while sending email.

```
package cs520.email;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Email")
public class Email extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Email()
    {
        super();
    }

    protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String from = request.getParameter( "from" );
        String to = request.getParameter( "to" );
        String subject = request.getParameter( "subject" );
        String content = request.getParameter( "content" );

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put( "mail.smtp.host", "localhost" );
        Session session = Session.getInstance( props );

        Message msg = new MimeMessage( session );
        try
        {
            msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( from ) );
            msg.setRecipient( RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress( to ) );
            msg.setSubject( subject );
            msg.setText( content );

            Transport.send( msg );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            throw new ServletException( e );
        }

        response.sendRedirect( "Email.html" );
    }

}
```

here i attached image about my output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov0JK.png)

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace from the logs **as text**, not as a screenshot. Also, do you actually have a SMTP server running on localhost?

Comment: SMTP 421 means that you've got too many connections.  From the [SendGrid description](https://sendgrid.com/blog/smtp-server-response-codes-explained/)  `421 – Your message was temporarily deferred by the recipient server. This is usually a result of too many connections in a short timeframe or too many messages.`

Comment: @stdunbar That is for errors on sending. This error seems to indicate a failure to connect. Likely because the OP has no SMTP server running on localhost.

Comment: You're very likely correct @MarkRotteveel - thanks for pointing that out.  Perhaps the 421 is an internal response in that case.

Comment: @stdunbar According to RFC-5321 error 421 is _"421  <domain> Service not available, closing transmission channel"_

Comment: So what @MarkRotteveel is saying `srikanth` is that your code is expecting there to be an SMTP server on your local machine and there isn't one.  Did your class indicate what SMTP relay to use?